# A term for a submonoid of a free abelian monoid?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

**Are there multiple ways of characterising which monoids are submonoids of *free abelian monoids*?**

**What *free abelian monoids* are**:

A *free abelian monoid* $\mathbb N^d$ with $d$ generators (where $d$ is an arbitrary cardinal number) is the monoid under addition consisting of $d$-dimensional column vectors with entries in $\mathbb N$, where the number of non-zero entries is always finite.

A *free abelian monoid* can be trivially understood in terms of multisets.

**Examples of submonoids of free abelian monoids**:

The submonoid of $\mathbb N$ generated by $\{6,10\}$ is not free: $6$ and $10$ are irreducible but $10+10+10 = 6+6+6+6+6$.

Another example is for number of generators $d \geq 2$, the free abelian monoid $\mathbb N^d$ contains a submonoid $M$ consisting of all $v \in \mathbb N^d$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^d v_i$ is even. $M$ is not free.

**Non-examples of submonoids of free abelian monoids**:

The submonoid of $\mathbb R$ under multiplication consisting of $\{0,1\}$. The problem is that $x^2 = x$ cannot be cancelled to give $x=1$.

Cancellative abelian monoids are not necessarily free as demonstrated by the monoid $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ under addition.

Cancellative and torsion-free (i.e. $n\cdot a=n\cdot b \implies a=b$ for all $n \in \mathbb N^+$) is not enough as demonstrated by $\mathbb Z$ under addition, which is not a submonoid of a free abelian monoid.

An abelian monoid $(M,+)$ is *not necessarily* a submonoid of a free abelian monoid whenever it is cancellative, torsion-free and $a+b=0 \implies a=b=0$. A counterexample as Wojowu suggested is $\mathbb Q_{\geq 0}$ under addition: It has no irreducible elements except $0$.

(**Tangential question**: Should I ask this on MSE instead?)

Comment: Affine monoid is used for submonoids of free abelian groups.  There is also a name for what you want but I forget it

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Affine monoids also need to be finitely generated

Comment: In your second example, isn't $M$ free on generators $(2,0,\dots,0),(0,2,\dots,0),\dots$?

Comment: @Wojowu Ah, sorry. I meant that the sum of the entries should be an even number. Will fix.

Comment: Also, your conjecture is false, as witnessed by $\mathbb Q_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. The monoid is countably infinite, so should be a submonoid of $\mathbb N^{\aleph_0}$ (which is an abuse of notation because we only allow finite-support vectors), but there are no irreducible elements except $0$.

Comment: @Wojowu I can keep changing the conjecture of course. I can insist that every element be a sum of irreducible elements.

Comment: More generally, if a monoid embeds in a free abelian monoid, then its Grothendieck group must be free abelian, in particular, it must have no divisible elements. This shows that for instance $\{0\}\cup\mathbb Q_{\geq 1}$ doesn't embed in a free abelian monoid, even though its elements are sums of irreducibles (all elements in $[1,2)$ are irreducible).

Comment: A finitely generated submonoid if a free abelian monoid is called a pointed affine monoid.  I don't know if the nonfintely generated ones have a name.

Comment: Maybe it should be cancellative, have finely generated free abelian Grothendieck group and non non-trivial units. This works in the finitely generated case.

Comment: @Wojowu Stop killing my dreams!!!

Comment: Corrected typos: Maybe it should be cancellative, have finitely generated free abelian Grothendieck group and no non-trivial units. This works in the finitely generated case.

Comment: The monoid should atomic and ascending chain condition on left ideal